# Is there a way to traverse tree built by React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to build a visual editor for an HTML page. It seems that ReactJS is good choice for that. Currently I faced with the following problem:

I modeled my data:

```
var Model = {
    title: 'Hello',
    description: 'Pellentesque eleifend urna ac purus tempus...',
    date: new Date().toString()
};
```

And built component which stores its data inside the above structure:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            value: Model
        }
    },
    handleMouseEnter: function (event) {
        $(event.target).css('outline', '1px solid red').attr('contenteditable', true);
    },
    handleMouseLeave: function (event) {
        var t = $(event.target), v = this.state.value;
        t.css('outline', 'none').attr('contenteditable', false);
        v[t.attr('property')] = t.text();
        this.setState({value: v});
    },
    render: function () {
        var v = this.state.value;
        return (
            <div>
                <pre style={{whiteSpace: 'normal'}}>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>
                <h1 onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} property="title">{v.title}</h1>
                <p onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} property="description">{v.description}</p>
                <p onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} property="date">{v.date}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In that particular case it works. But I want to get rid of `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` properties and to remain only `property` field. Like that:

```
<pre style={{whiteSpace: 'normal'}}>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>
<h1 property="title">{v.title}</h1>
<p property="description">{v.description}</p>
<p property="date">{v.date}</p>
```

I thought about creating mixin. Then, inside `componentDidMount` event, attach handlers to all elements with `property` attribute. But I found no way to achieve this.

My question is: **Is there a way to traverse tree built by React?** I noticed that *React Developer Tools* (Chrome Extension) can do that.

Similar Question: [React.js component creating parent child relations and iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20737720/1478566)

Comment: So you need a way to traverse the children components generated by the parent? In your parent, have a state that stores an array of your models. Then in the render, you can use ```array.map``` to iterate through each of those models in the array, and return a child component passing the eventHandlers and the model data from the parent

Comment: @trekforever bad solution. With it I need to have one more model -- for View from which DOM nodes will be generated. http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/6684/

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would want to do what you describe - perhaps further elaboration on what exactly you are trying to do that can't just be achieved with `array.map` ?

Comment: https://github.com/Cirru/cirru-fractal-editor

Comment: https://github.com/Cirru/cirru-editor I tried in two projects. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Seems to me that you are trying to do something that React can do for you..
If you want to traverse all _children_ of this component, you simply use the `children` property.
A better way, IMO, is to you just plain DOM methods in a mixin on `componentDidMount` where you can say something like `document.querySelectorAll('*[property]')` (non-jquery ex).
Don't know if the selector actually is correct..

Comment: Why are you changing the CSS with jquery instead of just having `h1.someClass:hover { outline: 1px solid red; }` in your CSS files?  Also I've heard `contentEditable` doesn't play nicely with React, you might want to read about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677931/react-js-onchange-event-for-contenteditable/27255103#27255103 for example before continuing

Comment: Take a look at Higher Order Components https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e

Answer (score 0):

So you want:

```
<h1 onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} property="title">{v.title}</h1>
```

as

```
<h1 property="title">{v.title}</h1>
```

I would use another `Component` for that, that takes care of the rendering of that specific type of components, like [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/) does.

The most simple approach to achieve what you want to do would be something like:

```
class MyField extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props); 
    this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this); 
  }
  handleMouseEnter() { ... }
  render() {
    const { property, children } = this.props;
    if (property === 'title') {
      return (
        <h1 onMouseEnter...>{children}</h1>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Then you would call it like this on any other component:

```
<MyField property="title">Stackoverflow</MyField>
```

A more professional, but also more difficult approach, would be redux-form implementation of [Field](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/Field.js), on which they even use [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to generate HTML (what I do with if-else in the example above).

If you need to access any of its data outside it, either you pass it a function through properties or connect that `MyField` component to redux (redux-form does this too).

I would also pass through props any specific one-time styles that you want to apply to your `MyField` components.